# Create a nested dictionary of an id and its relevant features and texts which is imbedded in another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote the function as follows and it works perfectly. It produces the result such as for any given id, it does a search in another dictionaries named (names_t and names_ft ) and insert the relevant words and its text into a dictionary called results.

names_t  is dictionary of id and text

names_ft  is dictionary of id and features

for the moment the function just search for one given id.

I would like to have it as a nested dictionary, such as for each id there is a nested dictionary  of its id and the given words and its text. How can I develop it further?

```
def exctract_ft_def(id):
    
    results={}
    
    text_ = [j for i,j in names_t.items() if i == id]
    features_= [j for i,j in names_ft.items() if i == id]
    text = [item for items in text_ for item in items]
    features = [item for items in features_ for item in items]

    for keyword in features:
        keyword_found=False
        for sentence in text:
            result=re.search(f'({keyword}): (.+)\n',sentence) #this searches for each keyword and captures any text after a colon+space and before \n
            if result:
                keyword_found=True
                results.update({result.group(1):result.group(2)})
                break
        if keyword_found==False:
            results.update({keyword:None})
        results = {key:value.split(' - ')[-1] for key, value in results.items()}
        
    return results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate throw a list of ids, like so.

```
def exctract_ft_def(list_id):
    
    results={}

    for id in list_id:
        results[id] = {}
    
        text_ = [j for i,j in names_t.items() if i == id]
        features_= [j for i,j in names_ft.items() if i == id]
        text = [item for items in text_ for item in items]
        features = [item for items in features_ for item in items]

        for keyword in features:
            keyword_found=False
            for sentence in text:
                result=re.search(f'({keyword}): (.+)\n',sentence) #this searches for each keyword and captures any text after a colon+space and before \n
                if result:
                    keyword_found=True
                    results[id].update({result.group(1):result.group(2)})
                    break
            if keyword_found==False:
                results[id].update({keyword:None})
            results[id] = {key:value.split(' - ')[-1] for key, value in results[id].items()}
        
    return results
```

With this you get an dictionary with id-keys and the values are another dictionaries (those you created).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the error is UnboundLocalError: local variable 'results' referenced before assignment
in this line ----> 3     results[id]={}

Comment: Did you miss the line `results={}`?

Comment: I get another error of AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
in this line
---> 23         results[id] = {key:value.split(' - ')[-1] for key, value in results.items()}

Comment: Oh yes, i edit my answer. It should be `results[id] = {key:value.split(' - ')[-1] for key, value in results[id].items()}`.